Pyside6 real-time data from input device; can't read from iodevice
The code below is supposed to just react on new data coming from input device.
However what is clear from the output, that the method IODevice::read clearly doesn't grab any data. I tried various options such as io=audio_source.start() and using returned IODevice. This version with buffer and array beneath it show that something is being written, however without hacks it is impossible to obtain it.
I can't figure out why I can't read method doesn't work.
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QDir, QUrl, QBuffer, QByteArray, QFile, 
                            QObject, Slot, Signal, QTimer, QIODevice, QUrl,
                            QMicrophonePermission, QPermission)
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import (
    QMediaCaptureSession,
    QAudioInput,
    QMediaRecorder,
    QMediaFormat,

    QAudioDecoder,
    QAudioSource,
    QAudioDevice,
    QAudioBuffer,
    QMediaDevices,
    QAudioFormat,
    QAudioSink,
    QSoundEffect,
    QAudio,

)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
from typing import Optional



class AudioDecoder(QObject):
    stateChanged = Signal() # add arg
    newData = Signal(QByteArray, QAudioFormat)

    def __init__(self,
                format: Optional[QAudioFormat],
                source_device: Optional[QAudioDevice],
                parent: Optional[QObject] =None,
                ) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        if not format:
            self.format = source_device.preferredFormat()
        else:
            self.format = format

        if not source_device.isFormatSupported(self.format):
            raise Exception("format not supported")

        self.audio_source = QAudioSource(source_device, self.format, parent=self)

        self.data_arr = QByteArray(10000, 0)
        self.input_buf = QBuffer(self.data_arr)

    def check_permissions(self, app: QApplication):
        microphonePermission=QMicrophonePermission()
        micPermissionStatus = app.checkPermission(microphonePermission)
        if micPermissionStatus == Qt.PermissionStatus.Undetermined:
            app.requestPermission(microphonePermission, self, self.check_permissions)

    def start(self):
        self.input_buf.open(QIODevice.OpenModeFlag.ReadWrite)
        self.audio_source.start(self.input_buf)
        def _newDataArrived(io=self.input_buf):
            #data = self.input_buf.read(chunkLen)
            print(f" Pos  {io.pos()}",  )
            bytearray = QByteArray(4096, 0)
            io.read(bytearray, 4096)
            print(bytearray.size())
            print(bytearray.data()[:10])
            print(self.data_arr.data()[-10:])

        self.input_buf.readyRead.connect(_newDataArrived)

        

def main():
    app = QApplication([])


    microphonePermission=QMicrophonePermission()
    micPermissionStatus = app.checkPermission(microphonePermission)
    if micPermissionStatus == Qt.PermissionStatus.Undetermined:
        app.requestPermission(microphonePermission, app, None)

    audioInputDevice = QMediaDevices.defaultAudioInput()
    audioOutputDevice = QMediaDevices.defaultAudioOutput()

    ad = AudioDecoder(format=None, source_device=audioInputDevice, parent=app)
    ad.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
4096
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
 Pos  12288
4096
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'Y7~\x84\xfc6\x8f^\x157'
 Pos  16384
4096
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x889\xd6$\xa39\xed\x05\xa59'
 Pos  20480
4096
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x9f\xb9\x84\xea\xa1\xb9\x97y\x85\xb9'
 Pos  24576
4096
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\xf2\xb9\x0cY\x00\xba\xa6\xa6\x0f\xba'


When the buffer is written, its position is automatically moved to the "end" of the data written, therefore trying to read from that point on is pointless, since there's no data written yet (or no data at all). There's also little point in creating a byte array with a reserved size if you are not completely sure about that size or you know that it will always increase (it won't be truncated).

bytearray = QByteArray(4096, 0) is to create a new array to bytearray, it doesn't read data from your input buffer. Change it to bytearray = QByteArray(data) with the data read from the buffer.
